# Is there a word for "the application of ointments/creams to oneself"?

Tags: british-english, old-english

I know there's a word for "the washing or cleaning of oneself, for personal hygiene, or the ritual washing or cleaning associated with religious observance" which is "ablution", and there's also "lavation" which has a similar meaning. These words got me wondering whether there's a word for the act that usually follows: to apply ointments, creams, etc. to oneself.

Comment: Sources on skincare use verbs like tone, condition, moisturise, care. It probably makes more sense for words to refer to the purpose or effect of the cream/lotion/makeup/product rather than the simple action of putting it on the skin (which might refer to a wide variety of preparations such as lotion, cream, gel, oil, etc, for various purposes). If you're wanting a noun, you should be able to find something. "Skincare" might be the most general.

Comment: You've got a lot on your mind... considered a holiday?

Answer (score 1):

In the religious/ritualistic sense, the verb is "to anoint [oneself] [+ with]" (Anoint can be transitive or intransitive.)

OED:

> 1. To smear with an unguent.
>
>    1. **To smear or rub over (medicinally or cosmetically) with oil or unguent; to oil, grease, apply ointment to.** 1611   Bible (A.V.) Rev. iii. 18   Anoint thine eyes with eye salve, that thou mayest see.

Note that the entry has not been updated since 1884, and is a little out of date as it indicates the word is archaic. I don't think that it is in the religious use.

More recently:

> "Women Writers of Ancient Greece and Rome: An Anthology
>   edited by Ian Michael Plant https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rJpGIrUUPPMC&pg=PA137&dq=%22anoint%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv5aXwi-DnAhURoVwKHStgCFEQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22anoint%22&f=false
>
> 5. To curl and dye the hair (1) First shave the head, then anoint the hair with cow-parsnip root in undiluted wine.

And OED again:

> 2. *spec.* **To apply or pour on oil, etc., as a religious ceremony:
>      a. at baptism, or on consecration to an office, as those of priest or sovereign.**
>      1867   M. E. Herbert Cradle Lands 168   Here David was anointed king over the house of Judah.